# rewrite rule returning page_not_found instead of first parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I can not understand why this is happening but I am unable to return the first parameter of url.

The url I am trying to rewrite is

```
example.com/blog?id=1234   to
example.com/blog/1234
```

the .htaccess is in the base folder where blog.php is but yet the following rules do not work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$                   /blog.php?id=$1 [L]
```

printing out the $_GET array shows the following:

```
Array ( [id] => page_not_found )
```

What am I doing wrong?